# How to use OpenLayers (Open Street Maps) examples with JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)?

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, openlayers

How do we use OpenLayers (Open Street Maps) examples with JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)?

I've downloaded the examples and saved them locally into a directory called "./ol/" and the ol.css and ol.js files are not listed because of some new "mapping" and "imports" used by JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)?

The https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html example works locally on my computer because it doesn't use the imports JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)?  Is it required to use the files from "v6.1.1-dist.zip" or how do we use the "v6.1.1.zip"?

```
https://openlayers.org/download/
```

I'm testing the OpenLayers (Open Street Maps) examples locally on my computer and having some difficulty getting the **imports** working correctly.

The example I'm using is the following.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/full-screen-source.html

**NOTE: I didn't want to use the hosted OL.CSS/OL.JS files**

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">
```

**the HTML code: "index.html"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Full Screen Control with extended source element</title>
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height:400px;
      }
      .fullscreen:-webkit-full-screen {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .fullscreen:-ms-fullscreen {
        height: 100%;
      }

      .fullscreen:fullscreen {
        height: 100%;
      }

      .fullscreen {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }

      .ol-rotate {
        top: 3em;
      }

      .map {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
      }

      .sidepanel {
        background: #1F6B75;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
      }

      .sidepanel-title {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 3em;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fullscreen" class="fullscreen">
      <div id="map" class="map"></div>
      <div class="sidepanel">
        <span class="sidepanel-title">Side Panel</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**the JavaScript code: "index.js"**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {defaults as defaultControls, FullScreen} from 'ol/control';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';


var view = new View({
  center: [-9101767, 2822912],
  zoom: 14
});

var map = new Map({
  controls: defaultControls().extend([
    new FullScreen({
      source: 'fullscreen'
    })
  ]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});
```

I'm not sure what this "package.json" file is used for but I placed it in the local "./" directory???  Is that correct?

Here is what the error looks like after I load the .js/.css:

[image: OpenLayer Open Street Map Error Message]

What exactly is a

> [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal 'ol/ol.css'. import
>   call expects exactly one argument.
>   (anonymous function) (index.js:1)

This error has something to do with the ***JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)***

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {defaults as defaultControls, FullScreen} from 'ol/control';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
```

I placed the "v6.1.1-dist.zip" and "v6.1.1.zip"? from https://openlayers.org/download/ in my local project directory with my "index.html" and "index.js" directory.

Let me know if you have some help or ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't JavaScript, JavaScript, this is... NodeJS!

Comment: the package.json is so that you can download the dependencies using "npm install" command on the terminal

Comment: There should be a way to do this without NodeJS.  I think for debugging in JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) it is required NOT to use a compressed OL.JS/OL.CSS?  Isn't there uncompressed version available from OpenLayers.  It shouldn't be required to use NPM just to use a OpenLayers?

Comment: Well, it seems that you need to use nodeJS JavaScript to generate the Browser JavaScript so that your example works. So yes, even if this is a just a browser application, if you don't want to use nodejs, you can... install nodejs, get the generated JavaScript that nodejs creates, and use that as your base JavaScript, and uninstall nodejs plus dependencies, slightly more complicated, but that's how they packaged it.

Comment: Be careful, it's unlikely that open street maps would require a NPM install just to make a map.

Comment: Well, the package.json has unmistakeably the npm install configuration format. Browser developer tools that you have an error associated with the first statement of the index.js script, which is not supported on browsers (yet/limited), but is standard in nodejs, and you can clearly see that the dependencies of the package the npm package "ol" is required, I would be extremely surprised if that doesn't scream, "this is a nodejs package, please use npm install". I think what you really want to do is how to use the openlayers library from just the browser https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol

Answer (score 1):

you can still use the software the way you described, however, the `import` statements will not work. Instead of importing the modules you can use everything from `ol` by giving a path, for instance instead of

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';

var map = new Map({
  //something
});
```

you can do this:

```
var map = ol.Map({
  //something
});
```

If you do this, you need to make sure you have openLayers as an `src` in your html file. [Here is an example how that could look like.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) You can either use the link from the example, or use relative links if you have it locally in your folder (obviously, after unzipping the zips)

If you look at the Docs, at the very top of each Class there is an import statement. If you use node, you can just copy-paste it, otherwise you can use the path and change all the slashes to points. So in order to use a `vectorSource`, instead of doing `import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';` you can say `new ol.VectorSource` .

As Rainb already stated, there are many reasons why everyone uses node modules and bundlers nowadays, but for getting started or for very small projects the 'old school' way still works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because it's not code made for the browser, this is code made for NodeJS.
Since 2010, webdevs have started to package code this way for various reasons, easier to manage, and you can use features that browsers don't support yet, and transpile them into things that browsers do support.

If we take a look at the [OpenLayers repository on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol), we can see that they offer you the possiblity of using browserify/webpack, that is just transpiling nodejs JavaScript into JavaScript that the browser can use.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol-browserify

Since this code is made for NodeJS, you do need to install nodejs in order to get the browserified version even if you don't want to use NodeJS.

On this repository, you will find instructions on how to do this, see which files are what you need and then you're free to use the OpenLayers library to do as you please.

Comment: Thanks for the tip/advice.  Also, if a user wants its possible to download the "v6.1.1.zip" from and uncompress them to a directory called "./ol/" from https://openlayers.org/download/
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./ol/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="./ol/build/ol.js"></script>

After that it is possible to get the example 

> https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: I'm looking at a way to "convert" the example so that the javascript code can run with the native OpenLayers html example.

Comment: you'll probably need to run browserify